# Problem with text datatype and UDF

Tags: user-defined-functions, sqldatatypes

I have this great function that parses a field into a pivot table consisting of four columns so I can sort my table accordingly. My only problem now is I can't use the function in a query that also calls a "text" datatype to be displayed in the results. Query runs fine as long as I don't include "spName" which is a "text" datatype. I've tried using **cast and convert** but neither built-in functions work in this query. thanks.

error:

```
Pivot grouping columns must be comparable. The type of column "spName" is "text", which is not comparable.
```

query:

```
SELECT title, recID, spName, [1] AS [Col1], [2] AS [Col2],[3] AS [Col3],[4] AS [Col4] 
FROM (select title, recID, spName from TestTable) t CROSS APPLY dbo.GetNumbers(title) PIVOT (MAX(num) FOR idx IN ([1], [2],[3],[4]) ) AS PivotTable ORDER BY Col1
```

udf:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetNumbers  
( 
@Numbers NVARCHAR(2000)  
) 
RETURNS @Results TABLE  
( 
idx INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
num INT 
)  
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @NonNumericIndex INT,  @NumericIndex INT 

    SET @NumericIndex = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Numbers) 

    IF (@NumericIndex > 4) --First Column not there 
          INSERT INTO @Results VALUES (NULL) 

    WHILE @NumericIndex > 0 
    BEGIN 
        SET @Numbers = RIGHT(@Numbers,LEN(@Numbers)-@NumericIndex+1) 

        SET @NonNumericIndex = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@Numbers) 

        IF(@NonNumericIndex = 0) 
        BEGIN 
            INSERT 
            INTO @Results VALUES (@Numbers) 
            RETURN 
        END 
        ELSE 
        INSERT 
        INTO @Results VALUES 
            (LEFT(@Numbers,@NonNumericIndex-1)) 

        SET @Numbers = RIGHT(@Numbers,LEN(@Numbers)-@NonNumericIndex+1) 
        SET @NumericIndex = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Numbers) 
    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

sample data

```
title                    recid           spname
QW 1 RT 309-23-1           1             This is title 1 words
QW 1 RT 29-1               2             this is title 2 desc
QW 1 RT 750-1              3             This is title 3 
QW RT 750-1                4             This is title 4 words
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Text` datatype is deprecated and sounds a dubious choice for a name field in any event.

This works for me

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestTable') IS NULL
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #TestTable
(
recid INT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(50),
spName TEXT
)


INSERT INTO #TestTable
SELECT 1 AS recid, 'QW 1 RT 309-23-1' AS title, CAST('test1' AS TEXT) AS spName  UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS recid, 'QW 1 RT 29-1', CAST('test' AS TEXT) AS spName UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS recid, 'QW 1 RT 750-1', CAST('test' AS TEXT) AS spName UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS recid, 'QW RT 750-1' , CAST('test' AS TEXT) AS spName
END

SELECT recid, title, spName, [1] AS [COLUMN 1], [2] AS [COLUMN 2],[3] AS [COLUMN 3],[4] AS [COLUMN 4]
FROM 
   (SELECT recid, title, CAST(spName AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS spName FROM #TestTable ) T 
   CROSS APPLY dbo.GetNumbers(title)
PIVOT 
(MAX(num) FOR idx IN ([1], [2],[3],[4])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: cool! i was running wrapping cast around title in both select statements verses calling the title alias in the first and wrapping cast around title on the second.